# Fatal exception: main Runtime error

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I get this in my logcat:

```
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.example.lightalarmclock.AddBox.setAlarm(AddBox.java:164)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.example.lightalarmclock.AddBox.onOptionsItemSelected(AddBox.java:147)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2642)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1039)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4247)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17728)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-11 17:11:42.161: E/AndroidRuntime(23599):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So the error is showing a problem on 164th line, right?

So here is the code:

```
private void setAlarm (SQLiteDatabase db){

    if (rep1 >= 0 || rep2 >= 0 || rep3 >= 0 || rep4 >= 0 || rep5 >= 0 || rep6 >= 0 || rep7 >= 0){
        repB = 1;
    } else { repB = 2; }
    timeSet= pos4+pos3+":"+pos2+pos1;
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE alarmStack(alarm_time, alarm_repeat, rep1d, rep2d, rep3d, rep4d, rep5d, rep6d, rep7d) " +
            "VALUES (timeSet, repB, rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4, rep5, rep6, rep7)");
}
```

Line 164 is the one with db.execSQL.

I guess I'm imputing values wrong but I can't seem to fix it so I'm coming here.
I guess the values in alarmStack(...) are viewed as variables but they should be a part of a string to indicate the columns I'm editing in SQL, but I cant find a solution or the right syntax for this.

EDIT:

So in the comments @user1676075 said that "db" var is null, to fix that I did this:

```
private static class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //writing to database
        if (rep1 >= 0 || rep2 >= 0 || rep3 >= 0 || rep4 >= 0 || rep5 >= 0 || rep6 >= 0 || rep7 >= 0){
            repB = 1;
        } else { repB = 0; }
        //setting time
        timeSet= pos4+pos3+":"+pos2+pos1;
        //Writing
        db.execSQL
        ("INSERT INTO TABLE alarmDB.alarmStack(alarm_time, alarm_repeat, rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4, rep5, rep6, rep7) " +
                "VALUES (timeSet, repB, rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4, rep5, rep6, rep7)");

        //launch backToMain
        //backToMain(ourCtx);
    }
```

But now for some reason it can't instantiate that dbHelper and I get this:

```
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lightalarmclock/com.example.lightalarmclock.AddBox$dbHelper}: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.lightalarmclock.AddBox$dbHelper; no empty constructor
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.example.lightalarmclock.AddBox$dbHelper; no empty constructor
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-12 20:47:42.852: E/AndroidRuntime(18656):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your LogCat shows that you have a `NullPointerException` on line 164. Put a breakpoint there, and find out which variable is null, then analyze why it might be null.

Comment: Regarding that SQL statement, it's been a while since I've made one in java, but doesn't that statement not extract the values of the variables either? It appears to me that you're executing: `INSERT INTO TABLE alarmStack(alarm_time, alarm_repeat, rep1d, rep2d, rep3d, rep4d, rep5d, rep6d, rep7d) VALUES (timeSet, repB, rep1, rep2, rep3, rep4, rep5, rep6, rep7)` rather than the values associated with rep1 and so on.

Comment: Not the cause of the NPE, but your SQL statement needs to be formed something like: db.execSQL("INSERT INTO TABLE alarmStack(alarm_time, ... " + "VALUES (" + timeSet + "," + repB + "," + ... + ")");

Comment: That SQL is trying to insert the literal values "rep1", "rep2", etc... not their integer values. That's at least one problem. Check out PreparedStatement for a better example of how to do it. But that should be giving you a SQLException, not a NullPointerException. A NullPointer implies that the "db" variable is null.

Comment: See answer from @shallOvercome, which seems to line up with the text in the exception saying: can't instantiate class com.example.lightalarmclock.AddBox$dbHelper; no empty constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got similar issue once and I had to add a default constructor with a super call to fix it. You can try it once.

```
     public dbHelper() {
       super();
     }
```

Comment: The constructor you have `dbHelper(Context context)` is an overloaded constructor, not a default one.

Comment: how do I make it work with an empty constructor? I get an error when I try to do that

Comment: You just add a new constructor along with the already present constructor.